# Add button in recyclerview to edit or delete data from realtime database

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i'm a beginner in programming so forgive me if my code is messy. I need some help to complete my program.

I'm using recyclerview to retrieve some data from realtime database and i want to add edit and delete button in the recyclerview to edit and delete some data.

I already create the button in the xml file, i just don't know how to code the button. I already tried some tutorial from youtube and refer to some code in some others post on stack overflow but most of the time the code will either give me an error or the button will not do anything. I've included my code and database structure below:

`DoctorViewAdapter.kt`

```
package com.example.patientmonitor

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import java.util.ArrayList
import kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer

class DoctorViewAdapter(private val patientList : ArrayList<doctorViewPatient>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorViewAdapter.DoctorViewHolder>() {

    //WebView
    private lateinit var pulseGraph: WebView
    private lateinit var temperatureGraph: WebView

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DoctorViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.patient_item,parent,false)
        return DoctorViewHolder(itemView)
        pulseGraph.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        temperatureGraph.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        pulseGraph.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        temperatureGraph.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        pulseGraph.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        temperatureGraph.settings.builtInZoomControls = true

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DoctorViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentitem = patientList[position]

        holder.userID.text = currentitem.userID
        holder.fullName.text = currentitem.fullName
        holder.userEmail.text = currentitem.email
        holder.phoneNumber.text = currentitem.phoneNumber

        var pulseValue = "null"
        var temperatureValue = "null"
        //get pulse value from thingspeak and set to text view
        val pulsequeue = Volley.newRequestQueue(holder.pulseValue.context)
        val temperaturequeue = Volley.newRequestQueue(holder.temperatureValue.context)
        val pulseRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, currentitem.pulseValue as String?,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                pulseValue = response
                holder.pulseValue.text = pulseValue
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                // didn't work
            })

        //get temperature value from thingspeak and set to text view
        val tempRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, currentitem.temperatureValue as String?,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                temperatureValue = response
                holder.temperatureValue.text = temperatureValue
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                // didn't work
            })

        //get thingspeak data every 1 second
        fixedRateTimer("timer", false, 0L, 1000) {
            pulsequeue.add(pulseRequest)
            temperaturequeue.add(tempRequest)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return patientList.size
    }

    class DoctorViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val userID : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserID)
        val fullName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName)
        val userEmail : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail)
        val phoneNumber : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber)
        val pulseValue : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPulseValue)
        val temperatureValue : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTemperatureValue)

    }

}
```

`PatientlistActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.patientmonitor

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class PatientListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var dbref : DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var userRecyclerview : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userArrayList : ArrayList<doctorViewPatient>
    private lateinit var viewPatientBtn : FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var doctorViewAdapter : DoctorViewAdapter

    //ActionBar
    private lateinit var actionBar: ActionBar

    //WebView
    private lateinit var pulseView: WebView
    private lateinit var tempView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_list)

        //configure Actionbar //enable back button
        actionBar = supportActionBar!!
        actionBar.title = "View Patients"
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

        userRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.patientList)
        userRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        userRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)

        userArrayList = arrayListOf<doctorViewPatient>()
        getUserData()

    }

    private fun getUserData() {

        //get intent
        val assignedDoctor = intent.getStringExtra("doctorID")
        val currentUserAccess = intent.getStringExtra("currentUserAccess")

        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        dbref.orderByChild("assignedDoctor").equalTo(assignedDoctor).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){

                    for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children){

                        val user = userSnapshot.getValue(doctorViewPatient::class.java)
                        userArrayList.add(user!!)

                    }

                    userRecyclerview.adapter = DoctorViewAdapter(userArrayList)

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })

    }

}
```

This is my data class
`doctorViewPatient.kt`

```
data class doctorViewPatient(val userID : String? =null,
                             val fullName : String? =null,
                             val email : String? =null,
                             val phoneNumber : String? =null,
                             val pulseValue : String? = null,
                             val temperatureValue : String? = null)
```

[This is my Realtime Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUOLS.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Last i tried, the button does nothing so i already removed the button code. I want to redo the button code from the start

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Can you please try to rephrase?

Comment: Sorry. Basically, I want to create a button in the recyclerview and for the button to delete the data displayed from the realtime database. I don't exactly understand the code so i don't know exactly on how to do that

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.